# C# download file once web-form is submited

Tags: c#, webforms, download, onsubmit

I need to automate downloading of a file from this site http://stats.smith.com/reports/Default.aspx using C#. The problem is that a web-form needs to be submitted first then the download takes place immediately. I can simulate the web form submit and the buttom clicks. However, once the form is submitted I don't know how to capture requested file. There is no redirection to the uri of the downloaded file. If there was I would have used function download(uri, filename) in webclient or webbrowser.

Comment: "I can simulate the web form submit and the buttom clicks." Just curious. How did you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) Class you can receive the response and save it as a file.